# If i run syncroniously on different threads does it makes it async per total?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, .net

I'm wondering if my application is getting strings asynchronously if i run it synchronously on other threads?

I don't actually know how to use the BeginSend/BeginReceive, so I used socket.Send(...), socket.Receive(...) on different threads and does that makes my application simulate async connection.

By the way, what happens if the string is bigger than the size of the buffer? For client i used telnet, but telnet actually sends the strings as soon they are get from the keyboard so I can't actually exceed the size of the buffer, but what if I used another client that sends the full string? Is there a way to tell the program that i sent more then the buffer allows it (through my variable `recv` that is the result of socketReceive)?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;

namespace CSharp_Console_Application
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate Socket GetClients();
        static GetClients newClients;
        static List<Socket> clients;

        static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPEndPoint serverIPEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9080);
            Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(serverIPEP);
            serverSocket.Listen(10);

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections...");

            clients = new List<Socket>();

            newClients = () =>
                {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
                    IPEndPoint clientIPEP = (IPEndPoint)clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint;

                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to {0}.", clientIPEP);

                    clients.Add(clientSocket);

                    SendString("Welcome to my server!", clientSocket);
                    return clientSocket;
                };

            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();

                newClients.BeginInvoke((itfAR) =>
                    {
                        allDone.Set();

                        AsyncResult ar = (AsyncResult)itfAR;
                        GetClients invokedDelegate = (GetClients) ar.AsyncDelegate;

                        Socket clientSocket = invokedDelegate.EndInvoke(itfAR);
                        IPEndPoint clientIPEP = (IPEndPoint)clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint;

                        Console.WriteLine("Sent 'Welcome!' to {0}.", clientIPEP);

                        string currentString = "";
                        while (true)
                        {
                            currentString += ReceiveString(clientSocket);
                            if (currentString.Contains('\n'))
                            {
                                Console.Write(clientIPEP + " said: " + currentString);

                                List<Socket> clientsWithoutThis = new List<Socket>();
                                clientsWithoutThis.AddRange(clients);
                                clientsWithoutThis.Remove(clientSocket);
                                SendToAll(clientsWithoutThis, currentString);

                                currentString = "";
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    null);

                allDone.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        static void SendToAll(List<Socket> clients, string message)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            clients.ForEach(clientSocket =>
                {
                    IPEndPoint clientIPEP = (IPEndPoint)clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint;
                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientIPEP + " said: " + message + "\r");
                    clientSocket.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                });
        }

        static void SendString(string message, Socket clientSocket)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message + "\n\r");
            clientSocket.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        }

        static string ReceiveString(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int recv = clientSocket.Receive(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);

            if (recv < 1)
                return null;

            string receivedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            return receivedString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May i ask why you just don't use the async method, when you want to send and receive async?

Comment: @Thanatos You ask what will happen if the string is bigger than the buffer? Well, TCP does not guarantee that 1 send is equal to 1 receive. So, what will happen when you do not receive your full string in 1 receive? What happens when it takes 2 or 3 receives to receive the same string that you sent in 1 send on the server? This is the same situation as 1 send being bigger than your buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

This way your `ManualResetEvent` is tend to be useless. As soon as you block the main thread, you release in the first line of `BeginInvoke` with calling the `set()`. And then you reset it again to set into the waiting state but another `BeginInvoke` call will unblock the code while the other `BeginInvoke` may still running. So in the end you will have multiple BeginInvoke thread and eventually you will have multiple exception or out of memory error.